# Pagination between separated data

Tags: java, mysql, distributed-system

I am troubling in this issue.

I am having 2 separated systems.

But I need do to a query that need the data from System A to query some data from the System B.

And the data from system B need to paged (20 records per page).

I can do this with with something like get 100 first record in System A then query in system B and maybe it can take 15 record from it then I need to take 100 more in system A to fill for page 1 of system B.

But for the total page I think i need to loop over all record in system A to do that.

I think it's very bad for prod when I have million record in each systems.

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks so much and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use a db view ( and consider a materialized view ).

Take database for system A, build a dblink on database for system B, create a view that joins the two data ( consider materialized view too ). If you have this view, use in system A.

If you cannot create a dblink, create an etl that reads periodically ( each night ? each hour ? depends on your requirements ) from system B, store in a table in database for system A and then make a view in your system A to use these data.

When you have all data on one system, you can consider some in memory database (like Redis, or similar ) to store key data and be able to query this "big data" efficently.

Consideration to do before start coding:

- always consider first why you do this and frequency: how many times each minute, etc..
- you have millions of data, but what about data growth ? How much this data will become in one month? One year? Ten year ?
- don't do a query each client request, instead cache result when it's possible. Not every client request should call two databases and consider how much your queries will impact on sytem B ( and if there are some limitation on this system too, lime rate limit, etc.. )
- maybe you don't want all data ( like all columns ) but instead a subset of data. Don't do a "join" with everything, consider instead only what you **really** need
- test with real world data, don't stop on local machine / test environment
- assume the worst: 10x data, 10x frequency requests
- consider how do you document all this and how to share this knowledge. Link a system to another is always a pain point in your architecture

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will try to use this idea.

Comment: you're welcome, if fits your scenario, consider to accept it and close it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions when it comes to system design. First I can think of is create a table where you can have id's fetch these from one database. once you get you pagination id's query to both databases. In 3 queries you will get desired result.

Second I can think of is do sharding based on id's. I am not sure what is you use case but if you want to paginate something for user. Make sure you save 1 user data in one database. In this case you dont need to go to second database to make query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my case the user information is stored in one db and in another system. But with this information I need to query it with these in my system then I need to do pagination for client side. And if I make a table just for query some information from another systems I feel that's not necessary and maybe it's not be approved by my CTO.